# Unrecognized field in JacksonXML

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I get this issue,where jackson xml cannot map the Ccy field from other CcyAmt class.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Ccy" (class com.currencyExchanger.codeAcadaemy.FxRate), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "Dt", "Tp", "ccyAmt", "CcyAmt"])
```

Why jackson cannot see the field Ccy field?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FxRates>
    <FxRate>
        <Tp>EU</Tp>
        <Dt>2023-10-02</Dt>
        <CcyAmt>
            <Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
            <Amt>1</Amt>
        </CcyAmt>
        <CcyAmt>
            <Ccy>AUD</Ccy>
            <Amt>1.6472</Amt>
        </CcyAmt>
    </FxRate>
</FxRates>
```

This is the CcyAmt class with the problematic Ccy field.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "CcyAmt")
public class CcyAmt {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Ccy")
    private String ccy;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Amt")
    private double amt;

    public CcyAmt(String ccy) {
        this.ccy = ccy;
    }
}
```

That's my FxRate class:

```
@Getter
@Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "FxRate")
public class FxRate {
CcyAmt ccyAmt;

    @JsonProperty("Tp")
    private String tp;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dt")
    private String dt;

    @JacksonXmlProperty (localName = "CcyAmt")
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper (localName = "CcyAmt")
    private List<CcyAmt> ccyAmtList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FxRate(String tp) {
        this.tp = tp;
    }

    public String getTp() {
        return tp;
    }

    public void setTp(String tp) {
        this.tp = tp;
    }

    public String getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(String dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }


}
```

I could not successfully find out what's the issue, it seems that the jackson does not reach the CcyAmt class?